# Querying three tables only one table has no association in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three tables in rails

This are the Tables

**Employee**   = (no association at all)

**User**    = has many attendance

**Attendance**   = belongs to user

then my question is how can i query the three table with this.

User table joins Attendance then also joins Employee where employee.code = users.Empkey

how can i translate it to join the three tables in one queries with rails 5

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178771/discussion-on-question-by-babyjohnchugulutgulut-querying-three-tables-only-one-t).

Answer (score 0):

You should create ActiveRecord associations between employees and users.

```
class Employee < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "code", class_name: "User"
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attendances
  has_one :employee, foreign_key: "Empkey", class_name: "Employee"
end

class Attendance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Now you can play around as you like.

```
employee = Employee.first
@employee_attendances = employee.user.attendances
```

Comment: employee is an external api based then the user get the "code" from the employee table and stored into "empkey" attribute for user table . .
how can i translate that to active record ? i used that earlier but it response with nil when i do this . . current_user.employee because instead of employee table belongs_to user i make it as a has_one : user.

Comment: then how about the migration ? we need to assign an index for the empkey in the schema? then how to put it when register using devise ? I'm just a beginner with this rails . .

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw sql in join table to join 3 tables like see in example

```
User.joins(:attendances).joins("Inner joins employees on employees.code = users.Empkey")
```

Hope this will help